# Operating System debugger for Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: debugging, ubuntu, operating-system, osdev

I've been doing operating system development (not building a Linux kernel), and have gotten to the point where I need a debugger, for my latest OS. I've tried Bochs (under my Win 7 partition), but that wouldn't recognize my USB (It's unformatted, I'm reading specific sectors right now.) and I would rather do something under Ubuntu 11.10.

Is there a Debugger that would let me debug a custom build OS for Ubuntu 11.10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I use [QEMU](http://www.qemu.org) for debugging a custom OS (which has [USB support](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/USB)).

Run QEMU as follows for a debugging session:

```
qemu -S -s [more options here]
```

- `-S` tells QEMU to not start the cpu. This gives you time to set breakpoints etc.
- `-s` is a shortcut for `-gdb tcp::1234` which start a gdbserver at TCP port 1234.

Then connect GDB to QEMU:

```
$ gdb
(gdb) target remote localhost:1234
```

From that point, you can use the normal GDB commands.