# How to use GDB in 16-bit mode?

Tags: c, debugging, assembly, gdb, x86-16

I have the following code, where I am trying to implement a function that prints string using the BIOS functions:

```
int printString(char* string)
{
 int i = 0;
 while (*(string + i) != '\0')
   {
    char al = *(string + i);
    char ah = 0xe;
    int ax = ah * 256 + al;
    interrupt(0x10,ax,0,0,0);
    i++;
   }
 return i;
}
```

The function interrupt is implemented in assembly. It calls the appropriate BIOS interrupt, as given by the first argument, with rest of the arguments containing the contents for ax,bx,cx and dx register respectively:

```
.global _interrupt
_interrupt:
push bp
mov bp, sp
push si
push ds
mov ax, #0x100
mov ds, ax
mov ax, [bp + 0x4]
mov si, #intr
mov [si + 1], al
pop ds
mov ax, [bp + 0x6]
mov bx, [bp + 0x8]
mov cx, [bp + 0xa]
mov dx, [bp + 0xc]
intr: int #0x0
pop si
pop bp
ret
```

Since I am using BIOS interrupts I am using 16-bit mode to compile this code. I used the following command:

```
bcc -ansi -c -o printString.o printString.c
```

I want to test this code in GDB, but when I try to load this printString.o file into gdb using:

```
gdb printString.o
```

I get the following error:

"/home/kern/printString.o": not in executable format: File format not recognized

I also tried changing the GDB to 16-bit format using:

```
set architecture i8086
```

But still this error is coming. How can I load a 16-bit code into GDB?

Comment: You can't run object files in `gdb`, no matter how many bits. You need to make an executable, as the error message says. For 16 bit code, you will also need a 16 bit environment, such as `qemu`.

Comment: @Jester But it is used in 32 bit mode with gcc. The command `gcc -g program.c -o programname` is used to generate an object code and is run using `gdb programname `

Comment: Yes, now play `spot the difference` with the two command lines. Notice that the `gcc` one does **not** have `-c` and produces executable (also hinted by the missing `.o` extension) but your `bcc` **does** have the `-c` (which means compile to object) and also the output has the `.o` extension.

Comment: @Jester ok..I also tried linking using ld86 command. But it still shows the same error. Doesn't ld86 produces executable code? Is there no other way to convert the .o file into executable and use it in GDB?

Comment: ld86 does produce executable, but that is a 16 bit executable that you can't load into your native operating system (which you didn't specify, but I assume linux). For the OS, that does not qualify as an executable. That's why you need something that can run your 16 bit code and provide the expected BIOS services. This is what `qemu`, `bochs` or `dosbox` can do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Jester says in the comments, you cannot run object file with `gdb`.

And you can not run a 16-bit executable file or 16-bit assembly code with `gdb`. You must use something like [`qemu`](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) to run your code on an emulated CPU and connect to it using `gdb`, or you can use [`dosbox`](http://dosbox.com/) in order to run your code and use a debug program on DOS. And remember, using BIOS interrupts is an error on a modern OS, like Linux, because at start up these operating systems disable BIOS interrupts.

Comment: [BOCHS](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/) has a good built-in debugger ([docs](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/doc/docbook/user/internal-debugger.html)).  It's highly recommended for bootloader development; it understands segmentation (unlike GDB), and can parse and print the IDT / GDT / page tables for you so you can double-check that you stored the right data in them.  It can also show you exception details.

Answer (score 15):

**Minimal QEMU example**

```
qemu-system-i386 -hda main.img -S -s &
gdb -ex 'target remote localhost:1234' \
    -ex 'set architecture i8086' \
    -ex 'break *0x7c00' \
    -ex 'continue'
```

where `main.img` is a [boot sector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22054578/how-to-run-a-program-without-an-operating-system/32483545#32483545).

- `break *0x7c00`: the first instruction will not be your boot sector, but rather `0x0000fff0` which does the BIOS setup, [see also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32682152/how-to-reboot-in-x86-assembly-from-16-bit-real-mode). So we use this to start from where the boot sector gets loaded to.
- `set architecture i8086`: for regular ELF executables, GDB can decide architecture from the headers. But for raw boot sectors, there is no such metadata, so we have to tell it.

See also:

- How to get source level debug info: [How to do source level debugging of x86 code with GDB inside QEMU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287181/debug-x86-code-in-a-vm)
- Similar questions: [Low level qemu based debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611624/low-level-qemu-based-debugging) || [Debug qemu with gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689136/debug-qemu-with-gdb) || [Debugging bootloader with gdb in qemu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242958/debugging-bootloader-with-gdb-in-qemu?lq=1)
- Some more good ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32960272/895245
- How to step over `int`: [How to step over interrupt calls when debugging a bootloader/bios with gdb and QEMU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24491516/how-to-step-over-interrupt-calls-when-debugging-a-bootloader-bios-with-gdb-and-q)